# ThreeJS scene with textures, why toDataUrl return black JPG?

Tags: three.js

I have a scene with 2 textures, that loaded from jpg. I make

```
 imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL(strMime)
```

and see black image. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520818/three-js-todataurl-png-is-black) and 
took from him this lines:

```
 texture.needsUpdate = true
 texture2.needsUpdate = true
```

but result jpg file is black square.
I make a [codepen with full code](https://codepen.io/tolyanor/pen/qvLNWd?editors=0010) for reproduce this case

How save jpg frame image correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it **after** call to `renderer.render(scene, camera)`, when the canvas is guaranteed to be initialized with some render output.

For example:

```js
var saveRequested = false;

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    // FIX: scene is rendered, ready to save it
    if (saveRequested) {
        saveAsImage2();
        saveRequested = false;
    }
}

function saveAsImage() {
    // say, need to take a snapshot after next frame is rendered
    saveRequested = true;
}

function saveAsImage2() {
    var imgData, imgNode;

    try {
        var strMime = "image/jpeg";
        var strDownloadMime = "image/octet-stream";

        let imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL(strMime);
        console.log(imgData);

        saveFile(imgData.replace(strMime, strDownloadMime), "test.jpg");

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alex, as you see in codepen, I make saveAs by clicking a link. So, renderer.render(scene, camera) is executed before click

Comment: pls try to apply my changes, I was not able to update your codepen example

Comment: Alex, sorry, I not carefully read your code at first time. i did as you said, and now all working good. Thanks!

Comment: Alex, I have one thought that I would like to discuss with you. Unfortunately stackoverflow does not allow to send private messages. If you are comfortable, please contact me tolyan.com@gmail.com Thanks!