# How to capture an image of THREE.Scene uning THREE.PerspectiveCamera?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was looking online, but I didn’t found much. I’m basically looking for the camera function that renders an image when a button is pressed.

Notice that I have 2 THREE.PerspectiveCamera (main and 2nd). The main camera is the one I use for the OrbitControls. and the 2nd is for capturing the image.

This is how I declare the Three.PerspectiveCamera:

```
camera_RT = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(20, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, -100, -1000);
camera_RT.position.set( //Set 2nd camera's position according to its parent
   camera_RT.position.x, 
   camera_RT.position.y, 
   camera_RT_Holder.position.z
);
camera_RT.updateMatrixWorld(); //Update camera's Matrix Wolrd (location in the scene)

//Add the Camera to the camera Holder (parent objects)
camera_RT_Holder.add(camera_RT); 

//Create 2nd Camera Helper (View volume)
camera_RT_Helper = new THREE.CameraHelper( camera_RT ); //Create camera helper
scene_Main.add( camera_RT_Helper );//Add the camera helper to the scene
```

[image]

***UPDATE:***

```
function saveImage(){

    let imgData;
    var final_Image;

    try {

        noLoop(); //STOP p5JS ITERATION - draw() function is not called

        camera_RT.imageData = renderer_Main.domElement.toDataURL();
        imgData = camera_RT.imageData;
        console.log(imgData); //CONSOLE PRINTS : data:image/png;base64,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

        final_Image = createImg(imgData);
        final_Image.attribute("id", "finalImage");
        final_Image.attribute("style", "display:block; margin:20px auto;");
        final_Image.parent(canvas_Parent);

        //Hide Scene_Main and disable slider
        document.getElementById("canvas_3d_element").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("slider-element").disabled = true;

        stage_9_declared = true;
        saveImageRequest = true;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return;
    }
}

function animate() {
    ...
    if(!stage_9_declared && !saveImageRequest){
        console.log(saveImageRequest);
        this.render(); //Render Scene and Camera every frame
    }
}
function render() {
    //Render only if the camera_Main is declared
    if(camera_Main_declared){  
        renderer_Main.render(scene_Main, camera_Main);  
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you could render the camera to a second canvas and use its `toDataURL` method?

Comment: Okay, I'll let you know if that works

Comment: this may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298242/threejs-scene-with-textures-why-todataurl-return-black-jpg/55300056#55300056

Comment: @AlexKhoroshylov it works but the image is blank

Comment: @Loizos Vasileiou, maybe you looked into codepen URL in the question? Check the answer too

Comment: Where are you rendering the camera view to the canvas? Can you add the relevant code to your question?

Comment: @ChrisG I have updated my question. `render()` would stop as soon as `saveImage()` is triggered.

Comment: I found out that I have to declare `preserveDrawingBuffer   : true` where I declare my renderer. This is required to support .toDataURL() for the final Image as explained in this [link](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/09/03/screenshot-in-javascript/). The only issue is that it captures the image from the first camera, not the one I want. So I have to find a way to change the renderer's camera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of taking a screenshot.

To change which camera the screenshot is taken from, you would just change which camera you send to the renderer.render() function.
In this example I only have one camera though.

**UPDATE**: The screenshot button in this example code may not actually work in the demo as it is in an iframe on stackoverflow (in Chrome, and maybe other browsers) because of [this](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5706745674465280).
But [here is a jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/art388yv/)

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh, material;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    // Renderer.
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true,
        //preserveDrawingBuffer: true
    });
    //renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // Add renderer to page
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // add Screenshot listener
    document.getElementById("shot").addEventListener('click', takeScreenshot);

    // Create camera.
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 400;

    // Create scene.
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Create material
    material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

    // Create cube and add to scene.
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    // Create ambient light and add to scene.
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040); // soft white light
    scene.add(light);

    // Create directional light and add to scene.
    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    // Add listener for window resize.
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}

function takeScreenshot() {

    // open in new window like this
    //
/*
    var w = window.open('', '');
    w.document.title = "Screenshot";
    //w.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    var img = new Image();
    // Without 'preserveDrawingBuffer' set to true, we must render now
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    img.src = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
    w.document.body.appendChild(img);  
*/
/*
    // download file like this.
    //
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    // Without 'preserveDrawingBuffer' set to true, we must render now
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    a.href = renderer.domElement.toDataURL().replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    a.download = 'canvas.png'
    a.click();
*/
    

    // New version of file download using toBlob.
    // toBlob should be faster than toDataUrl.
    // But maybe not because also calling createOjectURL.
    // I dunno....
    //
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    renderer.domElement.toBlob(function(blob){
        var a = document.createElement('a');
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      a.href = url;
      a.download = 'canvas.png';
      a.click();
    }, 'image/png', 1.0);

    
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
#shot {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/r102/build/three.min.js"></script>
<button id="shot">Take Screenshot</button>
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you very much. (Although I consist that there are two cameras. The one camera captures the other one with its helper - main camera doesn't have a helper). Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

On button click use the method toDataURL() to capture the image from the camera.
imageData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();

The DOM element of renderer is a canvas. Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL for more details

Comment: I have updated my question. This will create the appropriate url. However the image in blank.