# I need to convert a 3D model (t-shirt) into a png image

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I need to convert a GLB 3D model into a PNG image. I have three 3D models of t-shirts, and I need a png of each of them at the click of a button. I need to take the front picture of the 3D model (a t-shirt) and convert it into a png or any other image format.

I made a customizable 3D model of a t-shirt. Once the user customizes their t-shirt, they should be able to take a picture of the t-shirt to save it. I need some hints on how to do this.

Comment: Do you mean take a screenshot of your canvas with three.js? How about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193702/three-js-how-can-i-make-a-2d-snapshot-of-a-scene-as-a-jpg-image

Comment: I created a tool to directly create a screenshot from a glb/glTF url, you can try it here: https://www.flowkit.app/ Let me know if this is what you need.